# Why is django not picking up elif

Tags: django-templates

So i'd like to use this 'advanced' if elif constrution in the django template, but it doesn't seem to work? It just makes it all a regular

```
{% for recruit in recruits_list %}
{% if recruit.accepted == "Yes" %}
<tr class="table-success">
{% elif recruit.accepted == "No" %}
<tr class="table-danger">
{% else %}
<tr>
{% endif %}
```

If i juse juse the == "Yes" it works. If i juse just the == "No" it works. But not in this way. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I  re did the whole code, not it works. Things learned:

- inside {% %} code, you do not need {{ }} brackets
- Check for typos (i fixed mine above already, had succes in stead of success

Complete code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Recruit List</h1>
  {% if recruits_list %}
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" >Player</th>
      <th scope="col">Recruited on</th>
      <th scope="col">Eligeble</th>
      <th scope="col">Recruiter</th>
      <th scope="col">Accepted</th>
      <th scope="col">Vote is up</th>
      <th scope="col">Notes</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions<th>
    <tr>
    {% for recruit in recruits_list %}

    {% if recruit.%}

    {% if recruit.accepted == 'Yes' %}
    <tr class="table-success">
    {% elif recruit.accepted == 'No' %}
    <tr class="table-danger">
    {% else %}
    <tr>
    {% endif %}
      <td>{{recruit.player_name}}</td>
      <td>{{recruit.date_recruited}}</td>
      <td>{{recruit.date_eligeble}}</td>
      <td>{{recruit.recruiter}}</td>
      <td>{{recruit.accepted}}</td>
      <td>{{recruit.vote_is_up}}</td>
      <td>{{recruit.notes}}</td>
      <td><img src="{% static 'recruits/edit.png' %}" alt="edit" width=20px ><img src="{% static 'recruits/archive.jpg' %}" alt="edit" width=40px ></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no recruits.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```